# jquery code only worked after it was returned to console

Tags: jquery

html

```
<span><a class="like-Unlike" href="">Like</a></span>
```

my.js

```
$(".like-Unlike").on('click',function (e) {

        if ($(this).html() == "Like") {
            $(this).html('Unlike');
        }
        else {
            $(this).html('Like');
        }
        return false;
    }
);
```

Problem is :
the Like button doesn't work as a toggle button without error message, but after I return all the above javascript into console, it works.

Comment: What error? And what do you mean "after I return all the above javascript into console"?

Comment: Are the elements generated dynamically?

Comment: @Carcigenicate there is no error message. I copied and entered the whole js snippet into chrome F12 console

Comment: @ming Ahh, I see. Then I'd say you should answer Mr. Allen's question. You might be trying to toggle the element before it's been loaded. Add everything into a `document.onload` callback and see if it works.

Comment: Sorry, but I VTC this question as _This question was caused by a **problem that can no longer be reproduced** or a **simple typographical error**._, I tested and it works great. if you're adding the elements dynamically then it would be a duplicate of one of the many "**event delegation**" questions on SO

Comment: @Mr.Alien yes! they are

Comment: Are you executing the JS inside a $(document).ready() statement?

Comment: @ming [Read this](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) to learn more about event delegation (Basically this `$("span").on('click', ".like-Unlike", function (e) {`should work)

Comment: @MatiasCerrotta doesn't matter.. piece of code will invoke onclick only and not onload :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you confirmed that the elements are appended dynamically, these appended elements do not have the click handler attached to them. To make this work, you need to use event delegation. Instead of you attaching the event handler to the button, you bind it to the parent element, or say `body`, and modify the `on` like

```
$('body').on('click', '.like-Unlike', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); //don't use return false; has nothing to do with the issue though

  var elm = $(this); //cache the element
  (elm.text() == 'Like') ? elm.text('Unlike') : elm.text('Like'); //keeping it short
});
```

For more on [event delegation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1687296/what-is-dom-event-delegation)

Answer (score 2):

A couple of things:

1. When strings get larger checking of the exact match of the string will not be fun, so I decided to add in some `.data`'s.  I didn't use global variables to avoid naming conflicts and so your code can support more than one button.
2. I added in event delegations so even if you add it dynamically (via JS) it will still work.
3. Finally, for JavaScript-based links you should either do `e.preventDefault` or set the `href` to `#` or `javascript:void(0);`

```js
$(document.body).on('click',".like-Unlike",function (e) {
  var $el = $(this);
  if ($el.data("liked")) {
    $el.html('Like');
  } else {
    $el.html('Unlike');
  }
  $el.data("liked",!$el.data("liked"))
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span><a class="like-Unlike" href="javascript:void(0)">Like</a></span>
```

Comment: using global variables?? Horrible practice to be teaching people

Comment: @charlietfl I don't recommend that because if you have more than one like/dislike button it will cause issues.

Comment: I'm saying you are already using one...and it is a terrible practice

Comment: @charlietfl where's the global variable?

Comment: `liked = $(this).data("liked");` << here

Comment: But that's locally assigned inside the click function.

Comment: No it is not...that is not how javascript scope works

Comment: @charlietfl Updated.

Comment: @Mr.Alien Updated.

Comment: @nfnneil You're rewrapping `this` with jQuery four times on each click (if condition, changing the html, setting the data, getting the data), better to save a reference using a variable `var $el = $(this);` for example.

Comment: @Mr.Alien Oooops.. I deserve it for nagging you earlier

Comment: @AlonEitan Updated.  Thanks.  It does make the code cleaner and more efficient.

Comment: @nfnneil Now that's a good answer! (At least to me) have an upvote

Comment: @AlonEitan you didn't nag at all :) I appreciate people who clarifies before taking actions and corrects me too ..